# Using Pip for Python3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-16.04, pip

So I am trying to install packages, but they always install for 2.7.

I also cant get rid of 2.7 and I don't know how to change my terminal to not do anything for 2.7 but 3.x.

Whenever I `pip install`, it installs for 2.7, I just can't get it to run.

Also no matter what I try I can't get rid of Python 2.7, if anyone knows how to do that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Python 3 installed already? If yes, then you should be able to use `pip3` to install modules.

For `Python 3`

```
$> pip3 install <module>
```

For `Python 2`

```
$> pip install <module>
```

If you don't have `pip3` command,  try to install `python3-pip` package. Also, to run your script with `Python 3` you will need to run it like this:

```
$> python3 yourscript.py
```

And I believe that you can't get rid of `Python 2` as it is a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pip3` command to "pip-install" packages for Python v3. `pip3` is part of the `python3-pip` package that you may need to install first from the Ubuntu repository.